# React not being recognized as imported - ReactNative expo app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

Attempting to build an expo app (on my android device) and keep running into this `Can't find variable: React` error

My import statement is `import React, { useReducer, useMemo, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';` which seems to be correct from previous use and work. Wondering what could have triggered this problem after an admittedly long code rewrite. If you want to look at the full file I will link it in a pastebin below

https://pastebin.com/wXyhHf2v

Relevant sections I assumed would be wherever I call a subfunction of React, (like useReducer) as the React context may be needed inside the jsx, but not entirely sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is happening here but it happened to me once and I just made sure that

> import React from 'react'

is the first line of the file. This fixed it for me. I can hope it works for you too.